# How to obtain $P_{n-r} = \lim\limits_{t\to\infty} p_{r0}(t) = \lim\limits_{s\to 0} s F_r(0,s)$ in Gani's paper?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability

Currently I am reading [Gani's paper on the general stochastic epidemic](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bsmsp/1200513799).

At  page $277,$ section $4$ Total size of the epidemic, I do not understand how the author obtained the equations below.

$$P_{n-r} = \lim_{t\to\infty} p_{r0}(t) = \lim_{s\to 0} s F_r(0,s).$$

The context is as follows:

> Consider the probabilities $\{P_{n-r}\}$ of an epidemic of total size $n - r$, not counting the initial cases; then $0 < r \leq n$ will be the number of susceptibles remaining after the epidemic is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see early on in the paper the author defines $F$ as a Laplace Transform. Then that limit is just an application of what is known as the [Final Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem).

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which equality are you taking about?

Comment: It's on the one of the first few pages, look for the first time the definition of $F_r(w,s)$ appears.

Comment: Yes, I know that $F_r(w,s)$ is defined to be a laplace transform. But I do not see how it leads to equalities above.

Comment: @Idonknow it is just the application of FVT. It is quite literally the same formula, unless I have misunderstood the relationship between $p$ and $F$. Read the link.

Comment: I see. So the Final Value Theorem justifies the equality that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} p_{r0}(t) = \lim_{s\to 0} s F_r(0,s).$$ But I still do not see why $$P_{n-r} = \lim_{t\to\infty} p_{r0}(t).$$ Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @Idonknow you said it yourself, "$0<r\leq n$ is the number of cases left after the epidemic is over". In other words, its the limiting case of what happens in the far long term, after the dust has settled.

Comment: I see. So the first equality follows from definition.